# Add break or new line in HTML Table header section

Tags: html, css

As of now, both labels are displayed at same line in table header section. I want to add break in between these two words. How can we do that? I want to show TEST and line 1 and LABEL at line two in html table header section. Any clue?

E.g.

```
<th class="col-xs-2 text-left">Test Label</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a linebreak.. `<br>`

```html
<table><thead><th class="col-xs-2 text-left">Test<br>Label</th></thead></table>
```

Comment: I have added <br> in between label as well as I applied some CSS however it is not working. It shows "Test <br> Label". I see that, in your code snippet it works but not sure why it is not working at my end (in our application).

Comment: Earlier, I was trying changes at browser console and it was not working. Later I did changes in our repository and deployed on server. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: Good to see you fixed the problem. When making changes with the inspect element mode in your browser, make sure to choose "edit as html" (from the right mouse click menu) instead of just double clicking on the text when you want to change it. Only in edit as html mode you can actually write html. Don't forget to mark a answer as accepted if you found a working solution (both answers given are good solutions, up to you to chose the one you prefer)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Label</p>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```